# Why is Polonium-210 more lethal than other radioisotopes?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, biology, medical-physics

So it takes a single microgram or less of pure Polonium-210 to be lethal. Which according to basically all sources makes it the most toxic material or at the very least the most toxic element. But why is this the case?
Radon-222 has roughly the same energy per decay and the same type of decay, and yet the half life is immensely shorter at just under 4 days. Shouldn't it therefore pose a greater threat in the same quantity?

Comment: Can you please clarify why you expect that given equal masses of two isotopes with similar emission energies that the one with the *shorter* half-life should be more dangerous?

Comment: Shorter half life would mean a great number of decays within a brief time frame therefore at least in my mind, more physical damage.

Comment: Ok, you need to [edit] that information into your question. That will send your question into the reopen review queue so that people can vote to reopen it. And when it's reopened, people can post answers.

Answer (score 1):

Polonium-210 is an alpha emitter; it is deadly *when ingested* because its residence time in the gut is significant and the radiation damage it causes is not blocked by your skin. Furthermore, it is readily taken up into the bloodstream where its damaging effects are spread quickly throughout the body.

Comment: FWIW, the *biological* half-life of polonium is approximately 50 days. And of course radon is a noble gas, so it doesn't get bound up in chemical compounds in the body.